# Service Stack ormlite generate http response for tables linked

Tags: c#, sql, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I use Service Stack to store my data with an Ormlite database with an http-POST.

I generate the below class to store my data received in two different tables, my data are stored but I get an error 500.
I try to generate an valid message (201) when the storage of my data is successful.

```
/// <summary>
///     Define your ServiceStack web service request (i.e. Request DTO).
/// </summary>
public class NewDevice : IReturn<NewDeviceResponse>
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the id of the NewDevice. The id will be automatically incremented when added.
    /// </summary>
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Info fix
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string HumanReadableDeviceSN { get; set; }
    public string Hardware { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    // Soft 
    public string Firmware { get; set; }
    public string SwVer1 { get; set; }
    public string SwVer2 { get; set; }

}

/// <summary>
///     Define your ServiceStack web service response (i.e. Response DTO).
/// </summary>
public class NewDeviceResponse
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the NewDevice.
    /// </summary>
    public NewDevice NewDevice { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
///     Create your ServiceStack restful web service implementation.
/// </summary>
public class NewDeviceService : Service
{

    /// <summary>
    ///     POST /json/reply/NewDevice
    ///     returns HTTP Response =>
    ///     201 Created
    /// </summary>
    public object Post(NewDevice NewDevice)
    {
        //Db.Insert(NewDevice);
        // ----- Share information posted -----
        // ---- DeviceInfo ----
        Db.Insert(new DeviceInfo.DeviceInfo { DeviceType = NewDevice.Type, HumanReadDevId = NewDevice.HumanReadableDeviceSN, Hardware = NewDevice.Hardware, Model = NewDevice.Model });

        // --- Device History
        Db.Insert(new DeviceHistory.DeviceHistory { Firmware = NewDevice.Firmware, SWVer1 = NewDevice.SwVer1, SWVer2 = NewDevice.SwVer2 });



        // GET Last insert ID from DeviceInfo and DeviceHistory
        var newNewDeviceId = Db.GetLastInsertId();

        //var newNewDeviceId = Db.Select<DeviceInfo.DeviceInfo>("SELECT DeviceId FROM DeviceInfo WHERE DeviceType = LAST_INSERT_ID()", DeviceType, HumanReadDevId);


        var newNewDevice = new NewDeviceResponse
        {
            NewDevice = Db.Id<NewDevice>(newNewDeviceId),
        };

        return new HttpResult(newNewDevice)
        {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Created,
            Headers =
                           {
                               {HttpHeaders.Location, base.Request.AbsoluteUri.CombineWith(newNewDeviceId.ToString())}
                           }
        };
    }
}
```

This current class was used to generate a new table, I modified it to use only the http-post to get data and share them in two tables.

The row (var newNewDeviceId = Db.GetLastInsertId();) get the last insert ID of this former class implementation to validate the storage(Please, Tell me if I'm wrong).

But I want to get the last insert Id of the table where I store my data (DeviceInfo and DeviceHistory) to validate my storage.
I try to get it with an SQL request, but it don't work.

Please if you have any suggestion for my problem let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure your table has an **auto incremented primary key**.

Second, Be careful with multiple inserts. You should call GetLastInsertedId **directly after each insert**. Under the hood in SQL it translates into

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Your code should look more like the following:

```
Db.Insert(new DeviceInfo.DeviceInfo 
   { DeviceType = NewDevice.Type, HumanReadDevId = 
     NewDevice.HumanReadableDeviceSN, 
     Hardware = NewDevice.Hardware, Model = NewDevice.Model });

var newNewDeviceId = Db.GetLastInsertId();

Db.Insert(new DeviceHistory.DeviceHistory { Firmware = NewDevice.Firmware, 
           SWVer1 = NewDevice.SwVer1, SWVer2 = NewDevice.SwVer2 });

var newNewDeviceHistoryId = Db.GetLastInsertId();

// Then in any kind of select use the var not the function
var deviceInfo = Db.SingleById<DeviceInfo.DeviceInfo>(newNewDeviceId);
```